Clipping on a sine wave signal generate by QtCreator C++
dears!
I'm creating a project using QtCreator, this project is a sine wave generator, something like 60 to 83.3Hz sine wave generator.
And I using an osciloscope to watch this signal, I use an output audio from RaspBerry pi 5 as an output generator of this signal.
But, when I try to generate a 83.3 Hz signal, I have something like a "clipping" on it, from 100ms to 100ms, periody. If I try to manage others frequecy the code works very well, just when I use 83.3 this problem occurred.
I'm using a QtCreator and an audio output from a Raspberry Pi 5 to create this project. It's simple.
Thank u for support! =D
Follow a tape from the code below:
void MainWindow::gerador_frequencia(int frequency)
{
    stopSignal();

    qDebug() << "Gerando sinal de" << frequency << "Hz";

    int sampleRate = 44100; 

    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setSampleRate(sampleRate);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleFormat(QAudioFormat::Int16);

    QAudioDevice audioDevice = QMediaDevices::defaultAudioOutput();

    audioSink = new QAudioSink(audioDevice, format, this);
    audioIODevice = audioSink->start();

    audioBuffer = generateSineWave(frequency, format.sampleRate(), 100);  // 100 ms de áudio por vez

    audioTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(audioTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::onAudioNotify);
    audioTimer->start(100);  // Enviar novos dados a cada 100 ms para garantir reprodução contínua

    // Timer para parar automaticamente após 3600000 msegundos
    stopTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(stopTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::stopSignal);
    stopTimer->setSingleShot(true);
    stopTimer->start(3600000);  // Parar após 1h

    qDebug() << "Frequencia gerada com sucesso!!!";
 
    } // fim da void

    QByteArray MainWindow::generateSineWave(int frequency, int sampleRate, int durationMs) 
    {
    double sampleCount = (sampleRate * durationMs) / 1000;
    QByteArray buffer(sampleCount * sizeof(int16_t), 0);
    int16_t *data = reinterpret_cast<int16_t*>(buffer.data());

    double amplitude = 16000;  // Amplitude ajustada para evitar clipping
    double angleIncrement = (2.0 * M_PI * frequency) / sampleRate;

    for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; ++i) {
        data[i] = static_cast<int16_t>(amplitude * sin(i * angleIncrement));
    }
    return buffer;
    }

I tried change the type of variable, like int, double etc .. but its dont work ... and I tried change the time of sample to audio output too ... nothing happen ...

I have no idea what it means "clipping on it, from 100ms to 100ms, periody.". Also provided code doesn't look like complete thing.

What you have done is create 100ms sine lookup table at some frequency and then play it back. This will only work correctly if your waveform fits exactly into the buffer length. It is also possible that the DAC expects its data to be uint16_t biased so that "zero" is at the mid point. A picture of the waveform you see would be helpful.

dears! thank you for supporting! I have done this problem, 83.3Hz I have 8,3 cycles per buffer 100ms, or, 12.04ms per period of wave. And then, the 0.3 of 8.3 cycles is the problem, I need a complete number for use on buffer, not a decimal number ... 0.3 is not a complete wave, its a 30% of a cycle. For fix this, I used just 8 cycles por buffer, keeping the period of wave 83.3 (12.04ms), for this, my new buffer time is 96.38ms! Resume: for others int frequency, like 60, 80, 90, 100hz, I can use 100ms for buffer. But, for decimals frequency, like 83.3, I need to use 96.38ms or (int Cycle/period  = 8/12.04 = 96,38). For now, its work very good =D

